# codeigniter appends localhost with homepage url to signin page

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

Hi guys I am trying to login into my codeigniter project but I am encountering issues such that instead of redirecting to homepage after signin, it appends full url to the signin url as shown below:

http://localhost/prokazi/signin?redirect=http://localhost/prokazi/dashboard

here is the controller that extends all the other controllers.

```
class Pre_loader extends CI_Controller {

public $login_user;
protected $access_type = "";
protected $allowed_members = array();

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    //$this->load->library('csvimport');
    $this->load->library('Excel');

    //check user's login status, if not logged in redirect to signin page
    $login_user_id = $this->Users_model->login_user_id();
    if (!$login_user_id) {
        $uri_string = uri_string();

        if (!$uri_string || $uri_string === "signin") {
            redirect('signin');
        } else {
            redirect('signin?redirect=' . get_uri($uri_string));
        }
    }

    //initialize login users required information
    $this->login_user = $this->Users_model->get_access_info($login_user_id);

    //initialize login users access permissions
    if ($this->login_user->permissions) {
        $permissions = unserialize($this->login_user->permissions);
        $this->login_user->permissions = is_array($permissions) ? $permissions : array();
    } else {
        $this->login_user->permissions = array();
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code, please.

Comment: check the code I have added.

Comment: what does `get_uri([param])` function do  ?

Comment: @Badiparmagi  get_uri([param])  basically displays the requested url.

Comment: yeah, but I guess your problem is that function. can you add it to your question?

Comment: yes It is true that is the source of the whole problem.but how can it be solved now?

Comment: I have tried installing the project on some other machine and its working but this machine I am using has failed.

Comment: [`redirect()` will redirect to the URL](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect) you specify.  If you specify a URL like `'signin?redirect=something'`, you will be redirected to `http://localhost/prokazi/signin?redirect=something`.  AFAICT what you are seeing is exactly what you should expect.  Am I misunderstanding? :-)

Comment: I am also failing to figure out

Comment: So what are you trying to do, exactly? Are you just trying to redirect to `http://localhost/prokazi/dashboard`?

Comment: @Don'tPanic after successful  login its supposed to redirect you to dashboard url.

Comment: So why not simply redirect there? `redirect('dashboard')` or maybe `redirect(get_uri($uri_string))` ?

Comment: You have it in your code - redirect('signin?redirect=' . get_uri($uri_string)); . So you need to work backwards and find out why this is being executed ( In your code ) and determine if the behavoir - based upon your logic - is correct.

Comment: Obviously $login_user_id is FALSE or 0 and uri_string is true ( strange test) and not = to signin. So inspect these values using var_dump() or the  like to observe their actual values.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw when you var_dump($uri_string) I get 'dashboard'

Comment: @Don'tPanic redirect(get_uri($uri_string)) not working instead it is bringing error 'This page is not working' with too many redirects error.

Comment: Is this class being used to extend your signin controller? If it is, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading my xampp php version 7.1 to php 5.6 solved the issue.Cheers guys!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you put `redirect?` as a parameter in the redirect URL. Judging from your code you need to change:

```
redirect('signin?redirect=' . get_uri($uri_string));
```

to

```
redirect(get_uri($uri_string));
```

As others have noted, we can't see what the `get_uri` function does. You could pass the relative URL instead of the absolute URL to the redirect function (it seems your `get_uri` function creates the absolute URL). So:

```
redirect('dashboard');
```

Comment: thanks but that option would not work. remember doing redirect('signin?redirect=' . get_uri($uri_string)); it performs check on all the controller pages not only the dashboard. and doing redirect(get_uri($uri_string)); makes the page fail to load because of too many redirections.

Comment: Sorry missed that this is in the `__construct()` function. Because of that, you're creating an infinite loop. What you'd want to do is: in the construct check if the user is logged in and if not redirect to signin page, in config/routes you set the route for the dashboard page, and have the dashboard function in the same controller as you now have the `__construct()` function. This way, when someone accesses the dashboard without being signed in, that person will be redirected to signin. So you can't access the dashboard without being signed in.

Comment: thanks but still will not achieve the purpose because looking keenly at that  particular construct method where all controllers are preloaded you will realized there is so much information and permissions levels we are fetching before redirecting the user to the requested page.